# How can Cargo output binary files to the target directory of the current project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to output the binary to the `target` directory of the current project after setting `build.target-dir`?

Currently, all binaries are output to `build.target-dir`.

I know there is the `sccache` tool, but it still builds and uses more disk space.

I have two projects with the same name:

```
/dir1/my-rust
/dir2/my-rust
```

After compiling both projects, I will only get one "my-rust" binary file.

I want them to be outputted to their respective projects:

```
/dir1/my-rust/target/release/my-rust
/dir2/my-rust/target/release/my-rust
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a shared `build.target-dir`...

You can either specify a build directory globally (and Cargo will build there), or you don't specify it, and Cargo will build locally, relative to the project directories.

Answer (score -1):

`cargo build` has a `--target-dir` argument. For example, `cargo build --taget-dir ./target/` or `cargo build --target-dir /some/special/dir`.